# Searching in AlertDialog with single choice item list

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to achieve the following.

I have an AlertDialog.Builder, an ArrayAdapter with a select_dialog_singlechoice.xml and 3 buttons on the bottom of it.

Now I want to add an EditText field with search functionality (it can be on top of it or on the bottom, I do not care for the moment).

However, all my tries have not worked out so far.

I created a custom xml with an EditText and then tried it that way:

```
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    List<Run> allEntries = db.getAllEntriesOrderedByRunNumber();
    int checkedItem = 0;
    final int[] whichItemChecked = new int[1];

    if(mPolylinePoints.size()>0) {
        mPolylinePoints.clear();
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this);

    if(allEntries.size() == 0) {
        builderSingle.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.no_run_available));
    } else {
        builderSingle.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.select_one_run));
    }
    builderSingle.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_notification);

    // prevents closing alertdialog when clicking outside of it
    builderSingle.setCancelable(true);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MapsActivity.this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
    for(int i = 0; i<allEntries.size(); i++) {
        int count = db.countDataOfRun(allEntries.get(i).getNumber_of_run());
        arrayAdapter.add(allEntries.get(i).getNumber_of_run() + ": " + allEntries.get(i).getDateTime() + "\n"
        + count + " points to load");
    }
    if(allEntries.size()>0) {
        builderSingle.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.buttonWithoutColoring), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                int numberOfRun = allEntries.get(whichItemChecked[0]).getNumber_of_run();

                final LatLng[] latLng = new LatLng[1];

                ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

                executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //Background work here
                        List<Run> allEntries = db.getSingleEntryOrderedByDateTime(numberOfRun);
                        for (int i = 0; i < allEntries.size(); i++) {
                            latLng[0] = new LatLng(allEntries.get(i).getLat(), allEntries.get(i).getLng());
                            mPolylinePoints.add(latLng[0]);
                        }
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                //UI Thread work here
                                mMap.clear();
                                drawView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                textViewSlow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                textViewFast.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                        .position(new LatLng(mPolylinePoints.get(0).latitude, mPolylinePoints.get(0).longitude))
                                        .title(getString(R.string.starting_position)));
                                polyline = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().addAll(mPolylinePoints).color(Color.MAGENTA).jointType(JointType.ROUND).width(15.0f));
                                createCheckerFlag(mPolylinePoints);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        builderSingle.setNeutralButton("Show", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                int numberOfRun = allEntries.get(whichItemChecked[0]).getNumber_of_run();

                final LatLng[] latLng = new LatLng[1];

                ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

                executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //Background work here
                        List<Run> allEntries = db.getSingleEntryOrderedByDateTime(numberOfRun);
                        List<ColoredPoint> sourcePoints = new ArrayList<>();

                        for(int i = 0; i<allEntries.size(); i++) {
                            latLng[0] = new LatLng(allEntries.get(i).getLat(), allEntries.get(i).getLng());
                            //FIXME make speed adjustable
                            if(allEntries.get(i).getSpeed()>8) { //running is over 8-10 km/h
                                sourcePoints.add(new ColoredPoint(latLng[0], Color.GREEN));
                            } else if(allEntries.get(i).getSpeed()>6 && // jogging is 6-8 km/h
                                    allEntries.get(i).getSpeed()<8){
                                sourcePoints.add(new ColoredPoint(latLng[0], Color.YELLOW));
                            } else { // walking is around 5.5-6 km/h
                                sourcePoints.add(new ColoredPoint(latLng[0], Color.RED));
                            }
                            mPolylinePoints.add(latLng[0]);
                        }
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                //UI Thread work here
                                showPolyline(sourcePoints);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        builderSingle.setPositiveButton("Update", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this);
                builder.setCancelable(true);

                String numberOfRun = arrayAdapter.getItem(whichItemChecked[0]);
                String[] splittedString = numberOfRun.split(":");
                int intNumberOfRun = Integer.parseInt(splittedString[0]);
                List<Run> run = db.getLastCommentEntryOfSelectedRun(intNumberOfRun);

                final EditText edittext = new EditText(MapsActivity.this);
                edittext.setHint(run.get(0).getComment());

                builder.setTitle("Enter your new comment here");
                builder.setView(edittext);
                builder.setPositiveButton(
                        "Update",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                db.updateCommentById(intNumberOfRun, edittext.getText().toString());
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.update_entry), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                builder.setNegativeButton(
                        "Delete",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                db.deleteSingleEntry(intNumberOfRun);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.single_entry_deleted), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        });
    } else {
        builderSingle.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.buttonCloseDialog), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
    }

    builderSingle.setSingleChoiceItems(arrayAdapter, checkedItem, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // user checked an item
            whichItemChecked[0] = which;
        }
    });

    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customtrackview, null);
    builderSingle.setView(dialogView);

    EditText editText = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText.setText("test label");

    AlertDialog alertDialog = builderSingle.create();
    alertDialog.show();
```

This is my xml for the edittext

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Test"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the MapsActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relLayout"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.github.pengrad.mapscaleview.MapScaleView
        android:id="@+id/scaleView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginEnd="181dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
        app:scale_color="#009"
        app:scale_expandRtl="true"
        app:scale_maxWidth="100dp"
        app:scale_outline="true"
        app:scale_strokeWidth="3dp"
        app:scale_textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewSlow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="125dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="326dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
        android:text="Slow"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textFontWeight="950"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewFast"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="125dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="326dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="350dp"
        android:text="Fast"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textFontWeight="950"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabRecording"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="168dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_notification_overlay"
        android:onClick="onClickRecording"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabStopRecording"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="65dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="168dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
        android:onClick="onClickRecording"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabStatistics"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="225dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_bar_chart"
        android:onClick="onClickRecording"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabTracks"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="339dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_notification"
        android:onClick="onClickRecording"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabSettings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="282dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_settings"
        android:onClick="onClickRecording"/>

    <at.co.netconsulting.runningtracker.view.DrawView
        android:id="@+id/rectView"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="173dp"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

By doing it that way all my 3 buttons on the bottom are gone and the EditText is not visible at all.

Maybe, someone can tell me how to achieve what I am trying to do?

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: a custom xml with an EditText was created:

LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customtrackview, null);
builderSingle.setView(dialogView);

Comment: I posted my whole code now, including the xml.

Comment: Please post both xml files.

Comment: Sorry, that I have not included it before. It is posted now, too.

Comment: ???? You posted an xml of your activity. You suggested you had an xml with three buttons you used for your alert dialog. Your alert dialog uses two xml files i understood.

Comment: No, the 3 buttons have not been in a custom xml.
Maybe, it was misleading formulated since English is not my native language.

I just wanted to point out that the three buttons are not displayed and the EditText as well, if use my code the way described above.

Comment: You posted much too much code. And you should not post code of complete Alert dialog. We do not need the code when a button is pressed. Also database and allEntries, Executor service they are all irrelevant for your problem. And do without resource identifiers like R.string.no_run_available. Just go and sit down and fiddle an alert dialog code that demonstates your problem and that we can copy and paste and compiles out of the box so we can test. As it is now its undoable.

Comment: `This is my xml for the edittext` Sorry, i cannot follow you. You have for the secont alert dialog:                 final EditText edittext = new EditText(MapsActivity.this);  builder.setView(edittext); Why dont you do the same for the first one?

Comment: `and 3 buttons on the bottom of it.` You should have said that you had the usual positive, negative and neutral button as now it was confusing.